# Конвертация чисел в Hexadecimal, Octal, Decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как перевести числа типа

> 50 20 10 45

и т.п в

> Decimal 8 bits,Decimal 32 bits,Octal 8 bits,Octal 32 bits,Hexadecimal
>   8 bits,Hexadecimal 32 bits

?

PS нашел ссылку такого типа

Hexadecimal 8 bits
http://0x1f.0xd.0x53.0x24

Хочу сделать скрипт который будет делать такие ссылки.

Comment: Вам такой нужен результат: `'http://' + '.'.join(map(hex, map(int, "50 20 10 45".split())))` `# 'http://0x32.0x14.0xa.0x2d'` ?

Comment: Да, но мне еще нужно Octal и Decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для конвертации есть функции: [hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex), [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), [oct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct)

Пример:

```
numbers = [int(c) for c in "50 20 10 45".split()]

print('http://' + '.'.join(map(hex, numbers)))  # http://0x32.0x14.0xa.0x2d
print('http://' + '.'.join(map(str, numbers)))  # http://50.20.10.45
print('http://' + '.'.join(map(oct, numbers)))  # http://0o62.0o24.0o12.0o55
```